# background image does not cover whole body

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image for the body.

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: DaxOT, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url("background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color:#f00;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

The image does not cover the whole page. (like it should with background-size: cover) The body has the right size. You see the red area left and right. The effect occurs with IE and Firefox.

Snippet:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
      html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height:100%;
        min-width:100%;
      }
      body {
        min-height:100%;
        min-width:100%;
        font-family: DaxOT, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        background-image: url("https://picload.org/thumbnail/darlclgr/fond_blau-verlauf.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        -webkit-background size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-color:#f00;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything .. Post relevant code in a snippet or add a screenshot.

Comment: any fiddle or snippet showing your problem?

Comment: Create a [mcve], please.

Comment: There is a non-intuitive thing about the background of the `body` element that it effectively [applies to the `html` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#background). Try adding outlines to both `body` and `html` to check if it is the case or not.

Comment: attached snipped. sadly the problem does not show there... wtf.

Comment: If this does not work I think you got something else in your css that overrides it. `min-height: 100vh;`. Also what browser are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the height to it

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

and for this to work you'll need to add height in html and body too. Like:

```
html, body{
min-height:100%;
min-width:100%;
}
```

If this don't work then add this to body:

```
-webkit-background size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size:cover;
```